# Do I have to put "References available upon Request" on my Resume?

Tags: resume, references

From what I understand, it's uncommon to put full contact information of references on your resume.

In place of that do I need to put "References available upon request"?

Alternatively, is it safe to leave it out and leave that implicit? I'm afraid not mentioning it may make it seem like I have no references.

Answer (score 60):

> Do I have to put “References available upon Request” on my Resume?

In my years of experience as a US-based hiring manager, I always expect people to have references available when I ask for them.

I don't need to see the references themselves on the resume. I don't need to see a phrase "References available upon request" on the resume.

**It's perfectly safe to leave them off. I would never assume that anyone has no references.**

Another reason for leaving them off of your resume is that you want to be in control of presenting your references. When asked to provide them, determine how many are necessary, and choose which references will best represent you for this particular position. Contact your references so they will expect a call or email from this company, and discuss the job with them so that they can represent you in the best possible light.

Then give the list of references to the requester.

In your locale, the norms may differ.

Comment: Do you think this is country-specific?

Comment: I would says so, I worked in UK and after leaving my job there I asked if they give me reference and they said only type of reference they give is confirmation that I've worked here.

Comment: @Ajax1995 Incredibly so. In Germany you get reference letters and rarely call or contact someone directly.

Comment: Norms differ between locales. In my locale I have listed references for many years, as advised by recruitment agents. On the other hand, **none of these references seem to have ever been contacted.** I have recently begun omitting that section, in order to get (the local equivalent of) my résumé down to under 2 pages.

Answer (score 20):

Do not put on your resume, “References available upon request.” HR managers already know this and it’s a very overused phrase. Do not put the names and contact numbers of your professional references on your resume. You don’t want just anyone and everyone calling up your references every time they see your resume.

You should be in control of your references and know who is going to call them and when. Sometimes, recruiters and other companies will contact your references to recruit them. You’re the one looking for a job, so make sure that your references remain yours and out of the public domain.

Answer (score 4):

Be wary of putting your references directly on your resume. Unscrupulous recruiters may strip this information from your resume without ever contacting you and use it to develop their own business.

There is no need to mention your references on your resume, recruiters and hiring managers will ask you directly. It doesn't harm you to put "references available upon request," but it doesn't help you, and since a general rule of thumb is to keep your resume as brief as possible, why waste the space?

Comment: This answer adds nothing new to the previous answers. Please remember  to [not repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others).

Comment: I do actively advise against putting your full references and the reason for this. Should that not count?

Comment: Both Joe's and Michael's answers advise against putting reference info on a resume, and Michael's answer specifically says that "Sometimes, recruiters and other companies will contact your references to recruit them."

Answer (score 3):

This probably varies by region and culture, but here in the UK, you should leave out that statement.

The normal assumption is that you have some referees - it's not something that needs to be stated. Stating it could make you look naive.