# Is it ok to call 3 days after an interview for updates?

Tags: hiring

I did an interview last wednesday in which they told me they'd probably get in touch within a couple days, and they haven't. So I was thinking I could call to get an update and even if they chose another candidate I can at least know.

Do you think that'd look good or is it too soon? Also, would you take the opportunity to offer to give contact info of previous managers and mentors for references?

Comment: Related: [Do I have to put "References available upon Request" on my Resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12497) (not your resume, but same advice applies)

Answer (score 0):

Bureaucracy can move oh, so very slowly.

My advice to you is to wait for at least a week until you bug them about it. Something as simple as the hiring manager calling in sick for a day can end up delaying an offer by a few business days.

Comment: It's a startup though. I told them I'm on other hiring processes that are advanced when they asked, and the guy said they'd probably be contacting me "today or tomorrow", and it was last wednesday. I don't know man...

Comment: @mockingodist - oky doke, so send an email and see what happens.

Comment: @mockingodist - ok then, my suggestion is to call either today after lunch time, or Monday mid-morning (depending on your time-zone), and be super polite. The epithome of an enthusiastic, polite candidate. _"Hello Mr. X! It's Mocking Odist, I interviewed for the position of Y last week! I was wondering if you had any updates regarding the position."_

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think that'd look good or is it too soon?

It won't look bad. But I recommend you **wait at least a week before contacting them.**

> Also, would you take the opportunity to offer to give contact info of previous managers and mentors for references?

No. Provide those when they ask you so. What you can do is ask if there is anything you can provide to them, so *then* you can send them such material.

Comment: Well I meant to say something like "by the way do you want contact info of my references?", not to straight up give them their number. Other than that yeah I guess I'll wait a bit more.

Comment: @MockingOdist I see, yes in that case that is ok to do. You could phrase it like that or something more professional like: *"If you need any contact information or references please let me know so I can send them to you."*

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think that'd look good or is it too soon?

Yes it is too soon for a call, *but* you could send a follow up email proactively offering up your references.

After a week or so, I would then call for an update and after that I would **then stand by**.  If they want to hire you, they won't lose your contact information and they will reach back out to you.

Comment: Fair point. To be honest I don't have a week. There's something in my resume I want to change in order to increase my chances and I'm waiting for ongoing hiring processes to reject me (or hopefully hire me) so the resume they have is in line with my LinkedIn so it doesn't look weird. But I'll definitely wait a bit more I guess. I'm really anxious about this tbh

Comment: @MockingOdist At this point I would leave the resume as is until you as certain of the response.  **Always** make sure your resume is accurate, and I would make sure it matches up with LinkedIn as well.

Comment: To be honest after this change my resume won't be accurate. I left my last job for a new one and I got fired from that one really soon. However my old company closed shortly after I left so I'll pretend I worked at the prev one until then. I've been trying to be honest about what happened and hoped they'd give me a chance but it's ruining my chances, it literally feels like playing a rigged game. It's like they want me to lie.

Comment: Good luck to you.  Lying ( or misleading even a little ) almost always blows up in your face like an ACME dynamite kit.

Comment: By the way my contact in that company never reads emails. It's a call or nothing lol